# Loss of all data after reloading a docker on ecs

Tags: database, docker, amazon-ecs

I have a docker with a MariaDB database deployed on Amazon ECS. When I stop the task and restart it, I lose all the data in the database. Is there any way of configuring the task so that it stores the data somewhere and I can reload it afterwards?
I tried to mount a volume but it seems not to work...
Thank you

[The volume configuration I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97J7z.png)

Comment: Per the documentation for the docker image you are using, https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb It should be `/var/lib/mysql` not `/sqlData`. It's a lot more complicated than that though, since this volume will disappear if your underlying EC2 instance is ever destroyed. The better solution is to use AWS RDS MariaDB to manage your database instead of trying to build your own scalable database system on top of ECS.

Comment: I took your advice and created a base on RDS. It works well now. Thank you